# Asterisk Dial() - passing URL to softphone

Tags: asterisk

According to https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_Dial the Dial() application is capable of sending an URL to the extension being called. I suppose there are softphones implementing this, maybe popping up a browser pointing to the given URL - perfect to open up automatically a CRM customer page when receiving a call by identifying his caller id.

Do you know of any softphone implementing this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Doc have following line:

> if the channel driver supports it

For sip protocol will be issued SIP MESSAGE with url. So phone have support messaging via sip.

For jabber protocol will be generated jabber message.